# Extract a filename from json file path

Tags: regex

```
1. env\nonprod\alert\prj-data-02\alt\airflow-alert.json
2. env\nonprod\alert\prj-data-02\alt\biquery-alert.json
```

I would like to use regex to get the word before "*-alert.json" in the line. For example: from line 1 I would like to get the name 'airflow' and from line 2 I would like to get the value 'bigquery'.

Answer (score 0):

`.*\\(.*)-alert\.json$` should work. The parentheses mean it captures the words in them. There are ways of accessing whats contained in them but it depends on the implementation of regex that you are using. I think bash uses $<index> syntax for capture groups in pipelines and such. Here’s a [website](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html) that describes this.

Comment: I tried to test that combination here https://regexr.com/, but it is not successful